# how to check for multiple images != nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, if-statement, uiimageview

I am trying to check if multiple UIImageView `!= nil` using if statement and `&&` operator but the problem is that when the user pick any photo of the 3 `driverPImg.image != nil && passImg.image != nil && carImg.image != nil` the next code exuted and it will not check for the rest conditions

this image shows 3 images line up Horizontally all those images should be filled or not nil before the Btn change color to red but what it suppose to happen didn't happen

[image: this image shows 3 images line up Horizontally all those images should be filled or not nil before the Btn change color to red but what it suppose to happen didn't happen]

```
extension VC: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
        if let editedImg = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            
            SelectedImg = editedImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            
        } else if let originalImg = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            SelectedImg = originalImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            
        }
        
        if let image = SelectedImg {
            if pictureSelectionType == .profilePicture {
                driverPImg.image = image
                
            }else if pictureSelectionType == .idPicture{
                passImg.image = image
                
            }else if pictureSelectionType == .vhiclePicture{
                carImg.image = image
                
            }else {
                backCarImg.image = image
                
            }

            if driverPImg.image != nil && passImg.image != nil && carImg.image != nil{
                sendApplyBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.delevareColor
            }else {
                sendApplyBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            }
            
            
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
        
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Should the button be light gray if no image is selected, or if any one image is nil?

Comment: nope, same result

Comment: the button is just for checking the condition so it's already gray, after finish picking all the three images it should be turned to red that what I'm trying to do, but what I'm facing is when one image isn't `nil` the btn change to red

Comment: Then your logic is correct. Are you sure that the other images are `nil`?  Set a breakpoint and check with the debugger

Comment: Your code would probably be clearer if you use a `switch` statement for the selection type rather than a series of if/else

Comment: i did separate `if/else if` is to several if but still the same when I pick one image `btn` color changed and it shouldn't change till 3 images were picked

Comment: @Paulw11 can you show me in code and let me try it im just so confused right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check it by using your placeholder, which means if your placeholder image called "placeHolder.png"

```
if driverPImg.image == UIImage(named: "placeHolder.png") && passImg.image == UIImage(named: "placeHolder.png") && carImg.image == UIImage(named: "placeHolder.png") {
sendApplyBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

            }else {
                  sendApplyBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.delevareColor
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and created a snippet on playground. It seems to work fine, I have initialised required variables for code to work.

```
var btnColor = UIColor.gray

var SelectedImg: UIImage? = UIImage.init(systemName: "house")

enum PictureSelectionType {
    case profilePicture
    case idPicture
    case vhiclePicture
}

var pictureSelectionType: PictureSelectionType? = .idPicture

var driverPImg: UIImageView! = UIImageView()
var passImg: UIImageView! = UIImageView()
var carImg: UIImageView! = UIImageView()
var backCarImg: UIImageView! = UIImageView()

func imagePickerController() {
    
//    if let editedImg = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
//
//        SelectedImg = editedImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
//
//    } else if let originalImg = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
//        SelectedImg = originalImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
//
//    }
    
    if let image = SelectedImg {
        if pictureSelectionType == .profilePicture {
            let image = UIImage()
            driverPImg.image = image
            
        }else if pictureSelectionType == .idPicture{
            passImg.image = image
            
        }else if pictureSelectionType == .vhiclePicture{
            carImg.image = image
            
        }else {
            backCarImg.image = image
        }
        
        if driverPImg.image != nil && passImg.image != nil && carImg.image != nil{
            btnColor = UIColor.red
            print("Red color")
        }else {
            btnColor = UIColor.lightGray
            print("Gray color")
        }
    }
}

imagePickerController()
pictureSelectionType = .profilePicture
imagePickerController()
pictureSelectionType = .vhiclePicture
imagePickerController()
```

Make sure previous selected image is saved and not nullified for if condition to work.

Comment: if you give the first image a UIImage `let image = UIImage() driverPImg.image = image` you will get red even if the second or the third still `nil

Comment: I have edited your answer you can copy the code as it is