# How to detect UIImageView changed or KVO works on UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, key-value-observing

I'm trying to detect whether a `UIImageView` (`UIImage`) changed or not using key-value observer or any other possible method. My image view had an image when it's first loaded so it's not `image.image != nil`.
I'm using `UIPickerController` so when I pick an image the value will change. I want to detect that change so I can run some code. For example, change the color of a button or enable it.

```
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
btn.isEnabled = true
```

I have tried to add an observer this way but nothing happened. No printout, no break points.

```
let driverPImg: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DriverPimg"))
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 75
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return image
}()

let key1: String = "key1"

        // in ViewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.ProfileImg.image!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: key1, options: .new, context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == key1 {
        print("not changed")
    } else {
        print("it did changed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than `key1`, you should use `image` instead? That said, why are you trying to observe an image view's image? That seems like a weird thing to do.

Comment: cause i cant do this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183657/how-to-check-for-multiple-images-nil/64184228#64184228] the image view have a placeholder image so its not nil so i cant check if it is or not @Sweeper

Comment: How about making a `UIImageView` extension and override the `image` property? and then customize `willSet` and `didSet`?

Comment: can you explain in code please i don't know what are you talking about  for real, i have never used `did and willSet` in my life @RYZheng

Answer (score 2):

1. a `UIImageView` subclass
2. override `image` property
3. make some judgement in `didSet` method

```swift
class SUIImageView: UIImageView {
    open var didSetImageBlock: ((_ image: UIImage?) -> Void)?
    open override var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            print("did Set image")
            if let didSetImage = didSetImageBlock {
                didSetImage(image)
            }
        }
    }
}

let driverPImg: SUIImageView = {
    let image =  let image = SUIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DriverPimg"))
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 75
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return image
}()

// Set the placeholder image before `didSetImageBlock` . So the first time
// you set the placeholder image, `didSetImageBlock` won't be triggered. 
// After the `didSetImageBlock` is set, if the image of the ImageView is 
// changed, `didSetImageBlock` will be triggered. 
driverPImg.didSetImageBlock = { (image: UIImage?) in
    //
    print("did Set Image Block")
}
```

If you still want to use KVO, had better read this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-BAJEAIEE) first.

---

Comment: I know I'm asking too much but how is this answer my question how to detect image change I cant see a line of your code does that

Comment: updated. in your  first load ,  `didSetImageBlock` won't be triggered.

Comment: ok it's right and working i have multiple images in the same view can i trigger them all at once `if all Values change then do this`

Comment: and only if all `print("did Set Image Block")`

Comment: sounds like another question or you should edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

No one actually answered the KVO question.

See these docs for more info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using-key-value-observing-in-swift

```
class MyView: UIView {

    // The @objc part is needed for KVO to work
    @objc private var imageView: UIImageView

    // KVO
    private var imageViewObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    init() {
        super.init()

        self.imageViewObservation = observe(\.imageView.image) { [weak self] _, _ in
            // image view changed
        }

    }
}
```